# Memory leak in simple Google App Engine example

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

I seem to have a memory leak in my Google App Engine app but I cannot figure out why.

After narrowing down the lines of code responsible, I have reduced the problem to a simple cron job that run regularly and all it does is load some entities using a query.

I include the memory usage using `logging.info(runtime.memory_usage())` and I can see that the memory usage increases from one call to the next until it exceeds the soft private memory limit.

Below is the code I have used:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    _use_cache = False
    _use_memcache = False
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    ...[OTHER_PROPERTIES]...

class TestCron(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        is_cron = self.request.headers.get('X-AppEngine-Cron') == 'true'

        if is_cron:
            logging.info("Memory before keys:")
            logging.info(runtime.memory_usage())

            keys = models.User.query().fetch(1000, keys_only=True)

            logging.info("Memory before get_multi:")
            logging.info(runtime.memory_usage())

            user_list = ndb.get_multi(keys)

            logging.info("Memory after:")
            logging.info(runtime.memory_usage())
            logging.info(len(user_list))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/test_cron', TestCron)
], debug=True)
```

And in cron.yaml I have:

```yaml
    - description: Test cron
      url: /test_cron
      schedule: every 1 mins from 00:00 to 23:00
```

When running this task every minute, every 2 iterations it has to restart a new instance. The first time it starts with 36mb, and on completion it says

> This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.

But on the second execution it starts with 107mb of memory used (meaning it didn't clear the memory from the previous iteration?), and it exceeds the soft private memory limit and terminates the process by saying:

> Exceeded soft private memory limit of 128 MB with 134 MB after servicing 6 requests total
> After handling this request, the process that handled this request was found to be using too much memory and was terminated. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may have a memory leak in your application.

Below is the full output of both logs:

[image: Log 1 (doesn't break soft memory limit yet)]

[image: Log 2 (breaks soft memory limit)]

The output just alternates between these 2 logs. Note that I have disabled the cache in the definition of the model, so shouldn't the memory usage be reset at every function call?

Comment: Do you see the same decrease rates between requests (in this case from 110M to 107M) if slowing down the cron rate, say to 5 or 10 minutes? Also try to temporarily change the instance class to F2/F4 (or B2/B4) which should give you 256M/512M instead of 128M, hence more than 2 sequential requests before being killed) - do you see the same increase/decrease rates/patterns?

Comment: The decrease is not always there, it seems random. For instance these are memory figures for some other iterations (every time it takes 2 function calls before the memory is exceeded):
1)
1st call: `38.66 -> 87.13`
2nd call: `88.63 -> 134.19 -> memory error`
2)
1st call: `37.27 -> 84.68`
2nd call: `87.89 -> 136.57 -> memory error`

I then tried to reduce the frequency to every 5 mins as you suggested and there wasn't much difference:
1)
1st call: `37.95 -> 84.65`
2nd pass: `87.81 -> 133.38 -> memory error`
2)
1st pass: `38.15 -> 87.61`
2nd pass: `87.73 -> 136.43 -> memory error`

Comment: I tried upgrading the instance type to F2, and the behaviour is strange, here is the memory changes in the function calls right after upgrading the instance:
`38.58 -> 84.43`; `87.9 -> 133.2`; `136.58 -> 138.37`; `138.36 -> 138.39`; `138.39 -> 138.39`
We can see that it starts with the same memory usage and keeps increasing, but this time it stabilises below the limit and stays there. Looking at the logs later on (I left the cron job running for a while) I noticed that although sometimes it goes above 200mb or even runs out of memory (same message as with F1), most of the time it works fine.

Comment: How is it possible that when using F1 instances the memory increases until it exceeds the limit but this doesn't happen with F2 instances? If this was a memory leak then the instance type shouldn't matter right? But at the same time the function is the same every time, so if it's able to run it once (which it does even with F1 instances) then it should be able to do it every time unless something else is running on the instance (which there is not at the same time, nor between the different calls that I have shown), yet the memory seems to accumulate.

Comment: The F2 instance has 256M, not 128M. So it won't be kiled at 200M usage. The difference could be in the way the python garbage collector works (which I don't know exactly). Maybe relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37713846/app-engine-instance-memory-constantly-increasing.

Comment: It seems it does have to do with the garbage collector, but there is still something else causing a strange behaviour. I have tried adding `gc.collect()` at the beginning and at the end of the cron function and I have also set the instance type to F1 (limit at 128mb), and now the function manages to run correctly almost at every run. Still, from time to time it sees its memory usage spike and the error comes back, so there still is something strange.

Answer (score 1):

(I know this question hasn't been updated for awhile, posting this as I have been wondering about this behaviour in the past as well.)

I experienced the same issue for a while, and ended-up opening an issue on ndb's issue tracker. This behaviour was a bug of the `ndb` library.

This has been fixed in version 2.2.0, until then, according to the author of the fix *"in certain circumstances, [ndb was] not respecting `use_cache` for queries"*.

[Here is the link to the commit fixing this issue](https://github.com/googleapis/python-ndb/commit/802d88d108969cba02437f55e5858556221930f3)